# Facebook SDK / PHP example code doesn't work

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I have a facebook login tie on this site, but can't get it working correctly.  So I downloaded the latest php SDK and set up the example here:

http://thedrinknation.com/facebook-php-sdk-70030bb/examples/with_js_sdk.php

I've had some success getting the Javascript to work, but the PHP never is able to figure out who the user is.

(NOTE: the link I posted above is the CLEAN code downloaded from github - I just changed the APPid, and Secret ID).

I'm looking for some direction - do I have a setting wrong on FB?  Like application type, or something?

-Jim

Comment: You should post the source code so that people will able to help you. Remember to hide your APP id and APP key before posting the source code.

Answer (score 0):

JS-SDK is working in a correct way setting cookie and returning login status.

<strike>The issue probably related to the fact that your server never returning cookies back to browser. So every time page is refreshed new cookie is generated by JS-SDK. The only cookie it ever sent to browser is `PHPSESSID` which was send only if missing.</strike>

Seems that every time `FB.getLoginStatus()` is called new cookie is generated. Are you sure you have correct application settings like "App Domains" and "Site/Canvas URL"?

Comment: "The issue probably related to the fact that your server never returning cookies back to browser" --- why would server return cookies in each response? Give a sample of headers please as a proof of your point of view

Comment: Cookies are used to maintain session state, otherwise the user would have to log in for each page request.

Comment: I've never said it should be returned on every request.